# I am trying to connect two webcams in Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi3

It gives out an error saying "VIDIOC_QBUF: No such device, VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device" but it works fine when one of it is connected.

```
namedWindow("OriginalL",0);
namedWindow("OriginalR",2);
VideoCapture captureL(0);
if (!captureL.isOpened()) cout << "L doesn't work" << endl;
VideoCapture captureR(1);
if (!captureR.isOpened()) cout << "R doesn't work" << endl;

for(;;)
{
    captureL >> imageL;
    captureR >> imageR;
    imshow("OriginalL", imageL);
    imshow("OriginalR", imageR);
    if (waitKey(30)== 27)
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult or likely impossible to have two USB cameras connected to a Raspberry Pi due to USB bandwidth and processing issues

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=102098